# How to split by space but ignore it in multiple double-quotes?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to split different strings separated by space but I want to ignore spaces with in nested double-quotes, or any combination of double-quotes. Here is an example:

```
c "a " bbh "." d1
```

Output should be like this:

```
c
"a " bbh "." 
 d1
```

Or the other combination of double quotes like this one:

```
c "a "bbh"" d1
```

Output should be like this:

```
c
"a "bbh"" 
d1
```

Is there any way to exclude any combination of double-quotes from splitting?

*EDIT*

one more example:

```
c "a " bbh "." d1 kj "mn"
```

The output should be like this:

```
c
"a " bbh "."
d1
kj
"mn"
```

## EDIT

Thanks for your help guys. Actually I asked the question based on the data I have. What makes my question ill-defined is the bad format of the data!

Comment: When you say "any combination of double quotes", are you including an odd number of double quotes?  Do you want to exclude (from splitting) all text between the first and last double quote in the string?

Comment: How can you tell if `"a "bbh""` is one quoted string, or the strings `"a "`, `bbh` (without quotes) and `""`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Actually no, the number of double quotes are even, but we can't say all text between the first and last double quote in the string, because the string could be like this: c "a " bbh "." d1 kj "nh"

Comment: I have have same question as @Blckknght, then. I don't think your problem is well defined.

Comment: @Blckknght If I get you right, I want to split strings separated by space, but I want to skip any sapce within multiple (even number of) double quotes. In `"a "bbh"" ` there is just one space but I want to skip it and `"a "bbh"" ` is just one token.

Comment: Sorry, I am still totally confused.

Comment: How about `"a "bbh" c"`? I don't think there's going to be any easy way to tell if or where to split that (regex can't handle it).

Comment: @fyr0049 don't the examples in my question show what I am looking for??

Comment: @Blckknght `"a "bbh" c"` it is just one token.

Comment: I guess it only gets bad when there are more quoes later in the line: `"a "bbh" c" d "e"` could be one token (with four internal quotation marks) or three tokens, the first and last of which are quoted.

Comment: @Blckknght You are right!

Comment: So can you formalize how you know which quotes are quoting quotes, or should this be closed as Unclear what you are asking?

Comment: I have a way that works :) (with code).

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to use double quotes the way people would usually use parentheses. Your last example could be rewritten as

```
c (a ( bbh ).) d1 kj (mn)
```

In fact, it would need to be rewritten that way to be solvable at all. There's no way semantically of knowing that you want your example translated to the string above or to

```
c (a ( bbh (.) d1 kj )mn)
```

or

```
c (a ) bbh (.) d1 kj (mn)
```

and the more quotes in the string, the more ways it can be interpreted. In fact, these last two are more obvious interpretations, since the latter is how quotes usually work in a programming language, and the former could be considered sort of a greedy regex (like bcorso's solution).

So what you want is impossible, but if you changed it just a little, it would be possible via a recursive solution (but not regular expressions, since you need to check balanced parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

You could try regex

```
>>> strs = re.split(r'(".+")+', 'c "a " bbh "." d1 ')

>>> strs = strs[0].split(" ") + strs[1] + strs[2].split(" ")

>>> strs = filter(None, strs)
```

It partitions a string into everything before a pair of double quotes, everything between the double quotes, and everything after. Then it finishes the partitioning based on spaces for before and after double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but it includes separater (space) in tokens and also didn't work whit this kind of examples: `c "a " bbh "." d1 kj "mn"`

Comment: that's because that example is ill-defined. It's also easy to remove the extra spaces, but first restate your question so that it makes sense.